# Hide and reveal in blender 2.8

Tags: objects

I have just upgraded to 2.8 and upon opening up a project I was working on in the old version I find that only the object I last had active is shown.

Alt H is not revealing other objects event though they are in the outliner. In fact according the to the outliner, all the objects should be shown, but aren't

I am sure there is some small trick here. Can someone please help this noob out

super thanks

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE! From the information you have provided, it might not be possible to pinpoint your specific problem. Please consider editing your post to include screenshots and a .blend file (which you can upload to [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)). Thanks!

Comment: @ShadyPuck Problem description is clear, blend file isn't needed.